# How to resolve Uncaught TypeError: clojure is undefined

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I have done something to my clojurescript project which produces this error, I am using figwheel-main with deps.edn, not really sure what to look for to resolve this it sounds like clojurescript itself is not being found when run in a browser

```
Uncaught TypeError: clojure is undefined
    option_values_fmt http://localhost:9500/cljs-out/main.js:3842
    cljs$core$IReduce$_reduce$arity$3 http://localhost:9500/cljs-out/main.js:2534
    cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 http://localhost:9500/cljs-out/main.js:1626
    reduce http://localhost:9500/cljs-out/main.js:1623
    option_values_fmt http://localhost:9500/cljs-out/main.js:3842
    <anonymous> http://localhost:9500/cljs-out/main.js:3850
```

my figwheel file looks like this, one fo the changes I have made is to put a lot of the requirements in :extra-deps insteads of under :deps clojurescript and clojure are still included at the root.

```
{:output-to "resources/public/cljs-out/main.js"
 :optimizations :none
 ;:pseudo-names true
 :pretty-print true
 :source-map true
 :source-map-timestamp true
 :devcards true
 :main webpage.core}
```

What should I look for that might cause this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is a problem somewhere in your code, not your dependencies.

This for example can happen if you use a fully qualified reference (eg.  `(clojure.string/anything ...)`) without having required the referenced namespace properly beforehand (ie. `(:require [clojure.string ...])` in your `ns` form). The require ensures that the code is actually loaded and available before your code executes.

Comment: Thats got rid of that error, great I wonder why this worked previously it hass left me with Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined but i can do a bit more digging on that one.

Comment: You may have relied on another namespace that also referenced the namespace loading before the problem one. As long as the namespace is loaded beforehand everything is ok. The require ensures that things are always loading in the correct order.

goog not being defines usually means that the goog/base.js files wasn't loaded properly. When using `:main` that shouldn't be an issue though as the generated `main.js` should be doing that. Might be an `:asset-path` issue.

Comment: bit annoying it can compile when there is an issue with requires, the google not defined I resolved by changing optimization from none to simple, these are issues I have hit while trying to deploy basically, thanks for the assistance

Comment: @Oly This _feels_ wrong. Are you sure, you are not missing any require/import for goog things in your end?  E.g. a `git grep goog` should give you some inside on that in your codebase.

Comment: that search only brings up constants.cljs:(goog-define do-app-api "http://127.0.0.1:3000"), I assumed its because optimization none creates lots of files and trys to import them using the goog library, some of the others merge all those into one so I assume it something to do with that its another instance where the error is not that helpful